# Expressions for Multiplicative Inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given square matrices A and B, I am required to find an expression for the multiplicative inverse of A * B and prove that it works.

I have taken the from a theorem in a textbook that states that A^-1 * B = I and CA^-1 = I. I feel as if I could also use the proof that if A is similar to B and B is similar to C then A is similar to C for this since the variables in that statement are present in my original guess for this. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: What do you get if you multiply $AB$ by $B^{ - 1} A^{ - 1}$ (assuming the given inverses exist)?

Comment: @Gary Wouldn't we just get AB seeing that A = B^-1 and vice-versa?

Comment: @aoajimin_ Why would you assume that you have that $A=B^{-1}$? Also, if $A=B^{-1}$ then $AB=I$, and this problem becomes then very easy.

Comment: $AB \cdot B^{ - 1} A^{ - 1}  = A(BB^{ - 1} )A^{ - 1}  = AIA^{ - 1}  = AA^{ - 1}  = I$, now try multiplying them the opposite order.

Comment: @Gary BA * A^-1*B^-1 = B(AA^-1)B^-1) = BIB^-1 = BB^-1 = I

Comment: Thus, if you multiply $AB$ by $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ from either side, you get $I$. What does that tell you about $B^{-1}A^{-1}$?

Comment: @Gary This tells us that the same thing applies to the inverses of AB, right? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: It tells you that $B^{-1}A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $AB$. The inverse (if exists) is unique.